# Reduce Time Of Select Query on 50 Million Records Mysql

Tags: mysql, select, optimization

I have a database xyz with 50 million records and 20 column names.

One of the column names abc is having a unique index on it. I want to display this 50 million record of column abc with pagination.

Now I want to display pages with a list of 5000 name on each page.

My page say starts with -> http://www.test.com/display.php?page=1

Now when I type say page number 200 , The query does not display as it takes a lot of time and the page does not produce any result.

Could you let me know how to optimize it.

Comment: Show the table definition and the query.

Comment: You can probably use **EXPLAIN** to find out the bottlenecks in your query!!

Comment: Table structure id, name id->primary , name->unique index.

Comment: Query -> Select name from table limit x,y   where i show 5000 records in one page

Comment: We can't possibly answer your question without seeing the query and the table definitions.